# Time complexity of $L=\{a^nb^n | n \ge 1\}$

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, time-complexity

Consider the following language:

$$L=\{a^nb^n | n \ge 1\}$$

I constructed the following Turing Machine:

\begin{eqnarray}
T &=& (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, B, F) \nonumber \\
Q &=& \{q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4\} \nonumber \\
\Sigma &=& \{a, b\} \nonumber \\
\Gamma &=& \{a, b, X, Y, B\} \nonumber \\
F &=& \{q_4\} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

[image]

[image]

When the input comes as $aabb$, the Turing Machine works like this:

[image]

How can you know the time complexity of this Turing Machine?

Comment: "how it works" does not mean the transition diagram… I meant describe the steps with words in english.

Comment: @Nathaniel I editted it.

Answer (score 2):

If I correclty understand the algorithm, your TM starts "marking" the first $a$, then it finds the first $b$ and marks it, then it comes back the the first unmarked $a$ and so on. So, assuming that you have in input a string $w$ of lenght $n$ that belongs to the language $L$, you have $\frac{n}{2}$ $a$'s that have to match with the same number of $b$, each $a$ is paired to a $b$ that is $\frac{n}{2}$ cells away, so to perform a complete matching you need $\frac{n}{2}$ transitions from an $a$ to reach the $b$ to be coupled with it, and again $\frac{n}{2}$ transitions to reach the next $a$, so in total $n\cdot \frac{n}{2}$ transitions (actually, you have to perform an extra transition for each letter to put the head in the right place, so the exact amount of transitions is $\frac{n^2}{2}+n+1=O(n^2)$).

Now, let us consider a word $w$ of lenght $n$ that *does not* belong to the language $L$. If it start with $b$, it is immediately rejected, so suppose $w=a^hb^kv$, where $v\in a\Sigma^*$ has lenght $j>0$ and $h+k+j=n$. If $k\leq h$, then the TM will performs $\frac{k^2}{2}+k+1$ transitions before stopping (and rejecting $w$), while if $k>h$, then it will make $\frac{h^2}{2}+h+1$ transitions. So, the worst case correspond to the maximum of the function
$$
f(h,k,j)=\cases{\frac{k^2}{2}+k+1, \quad k\leq h\\ \frac{h^2}{2}+h+1,\quad k> h}
$$
on the constraint $h+k+j=n$, $j>0$, and it is not difficult to see that it is reached for $|h-k|=1$ and $j=1$.

Summing up: the worst case is reached when $w$ belongs to the language $L$, and the TM must carry out $O(|w|^2)$ transitions.

---

If you want to play with your TM and see the exact number of transitions, go [here](http://turingmachinesimulator.com/shared/xsxdvohbjh), compile and load a word, enjoy!

Comment: Thank you so much! It is so helpful

Comment: So the time complexity is $\Theta(n^2)$. It is also $O(n^3)$, $\Omega(n)$, and so on.